# It is the series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{ {(\frac{n}{e})}^n}{n!}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It  is  the  series  $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{ {(\frac{n}{e})}^n}{n!}$  convergent? I  tried  to  apply some  basic  criterion...

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 2):

Use *equivalents* and *Stirling's formula*:

$$\frac{\bigl(\frac n{\mathrm e}\bigl)^n}{n!}\sim_\infty\frac{\bigl(\frac n{\mathrm e}\bigl)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\bigl(\frac n{\mathrm e}\bigl)^n}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
and the latter diverges.